# Stratified Cross Validation with StratifiedKFold after cross_validation.StratifiedKFold deprecation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm following some sample script from 3 years ago and came across a function definition using a deprecated function (cross_validation.StratifiedKFold).

Here's the orginal code snippet from 3 years ago:

```
def stratified_cv(X, y, clf_class, shuffle=True, n_folds=10, **kwargs):
    stratified_k_fold = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=shuffle)
    y_pred = y.copy()
    # ii -> train
    # jj -> test indices
    for ii, jj in stratified_k_fold: 
        X_train, X_test = X[ii], X[jj]
        y_train = y[ii]
        clf = clf_class(**kwargs)
        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        y_pred[jj] = clf.predict(X_test)
    return y_pred
```

I've tried updating it by following some documentation on sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) and this is what I have so far:

```
## Attempt to modernize with StratifiedKFold from sklearn.model_selection
def stratified_cv(X, y, clf_class, shuffle=True, n_splits=10, **kwargs):
    stratified_k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits)
    y_pred = y.copy()
    # ii -> train
    # jj -> test indices
    for ii, jj in stratified_k_fold: 
        X_train, X_test = X[ii], X[jj]
        y_train = y[ii]
        clf = clf_class(**kwargs)
        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        y_pred[jj] = clf.predict(X_test)
    return y_pred
```

I then try to run the following chunk and get hit with the subsequent error:

```
print('Gradient Boosting Classifier:  {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier))))
print('Support vector machine(SVM):   {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, svm.SVC))))
print('Random Forest Classifier:      {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, ensemble.RandomForestClassifier))))
print('K Nearest Neighbor Classifier: {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier))))
print('Logistic Regression:           {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, linear_model.LogisticRegression))))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-a61be22f8ca9> in <module>
----> 1 print('Gradient Boosting Classifier:  {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier))))
      2 print('Support vector machine(SVM):   {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, svm.SVC))))
      3 print('Random Forest Classifier:      {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, ensemble.RandomForestClassifier))))
      4 print('K Nearest Neighbor Classifier: {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier))))
      5 print('Logistic Regression:           {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, linear_model.LogisticRegression))))

<ipython-input-121-e373d74b2cca> in stratified_cv(X, y, clf_class, shuffle, n_splits, **kwargs)
      5     # ii -> train
      6     # jj -> test indices
----> 7     for ii, jj in stratified_k_fold:
      8         X_train, X_test = X[ii], X[jj]
      9         y_train = y[ii]

TypeError: 'StratifiedKFold' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StratifiedKFold to split your data, without changing your code too much, below should work:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import svm

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

def stratified_cv(X, y, clf_class, shuffle=True, n_splits=10, **kwargs):
    stratified_k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits)
    y_pred = y.copy()

    for ii,jj in stratified_k_fold.split(X, y):
            
        y_train = y[ii]
        X_train, X_test = X[ii], X[jj]
        clf = clf_class(**kwargs)
        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        y_pred[jj] = clf.predict(X_test)
    return y_pred
    
print('Gradient Boosting Classifier:  {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(y, stratified_cv(X, y, svm.SVC))))
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks so much :D